# Variable declared as Node *&ptr = root->mRight

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, types

I am trying to understand what that means
I know that declares a variable to an address of type node and that & gets the address of a variable.  I also know that in a function parameter it is a call by reference pointer.  But I have never seen it in a variable declaration before...
What does it mean exactly

```
Node *&ptr = root->mRight
```

I know about working with pointers and everything I am mostly asking about the Node *& variable type. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the right, `root` is a pointer to a node. `root->mRight` is a member of that node, namely its `mright`, which is another pointer to a node.

On the left, we declare something (before assigning a value to it with `=`). If it were `Node *ptr`, it would be a pointer to a node, but because of that `&`, it is not such a thing in its own right, it is only a reference, an alias of another such thing that already exists. So `ptr` is just another name for the pointer `root->mRight`.

Comment: Ok, so it is exactly like when used for call by reference params.  If I change ptr such as ptr = someOtherPtr, then root->mRight will point to someOtherPtr as well?

Comment: @Bear: yes (except that it will not *point to* `someOtherPointer`, it will become *equal to* `someOtherPointer`, and therefore point to what `someOtherPointer` points to).

Comment: Ok thank you, You clarified it exactly.  I will mark your answer!  I thought this was the case but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this --> `Node *&ptr = root->mRight`
you compare it with this

```
int a =5;
int & al = a;
```

here "al" is just another name of "a"

now replace

```
int -> Node *
a   -> root->mright
ptr ->al
```

so you will understand that here "mRight" is a pointer to Node and ptr is just another name of "mRight".